# How to run only failed sessions in a workflow

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

In a workflow there are sessions connected in parallel and in sequence. Suppose some sessions which are in parallel and in sequential mode are failed, How do I restart the workflow with only failed sessions. How can I design this in Informatica?

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn 'suspend on error' for workflow
2. Turn 'restart on recovery' for each session in workflow

Now if any session fail workflow will be suspended until you fix the problem and hit recover on workflow in monitor. When you do so it cause to restart only failed sessions.

Answer (score 0):

A large publishing client asked us to implement something similar to what you asked. We crated a database table to keep track of successful sessions within a workflow. Each session will have a mapping at the end that adds an entry to database which says I passed or failed. When we try to run in a recovery mode we query the database at the beginning of each session to find out if we need to run this session or not.

We also provided a web interface to this table where business users can manually choose which session to run or escape based on their needs.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery option will work only if you have "workflow recovery" turned on in repository.  If you dont, then you can check option "fail workflow if task fails" at individual session level and create condition on link that connect workflow to each other.  Disadvantage of this method is that your workflow will appear failed and wont execute next sessions until failed one are fixed.

thanks.