# Running workflow from failed session

Tags: informatica

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run only failed sessions in a workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427128/how-to-run-only-failed-sessions-in-a-workflow)

This is a question which is already asked...
In a workflow there are sessions connected in parallel and in sequence. Suppose some sessions which are in parallel and in sequential mode are failed, How do I restart the workflow with only failed sessions. How can I design this in Informatica?
...
i saw the answer that we wil update database with status and then when we start workflow, before each session we will check the status and run if it is failed. How we will check this from session? How this is acheived?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write custom shell scripts for this and before each session include a command task that will connect to the database and check for the success records.

You can find the information in Informatica's Repository tables REP_WFLOW_RUN and REP_SESS_LOG tables for the latest runs. IF you need more controlled logging, you can write custom code to implement these.

You can look at some of the template code in the links mentioned below. However, the scripts I have written are to check event waits . You'll have to modify them, but this should give you a general idea.

http://www.etl-developer.com/2011/04/workflow-dependency-in-informatica-part-2-load-status-entries/
http://www.etl-developer.com/2011/12/extending-functionality-using-command-tasks-informatica/